# Invalid Argument Error when running Tensorflow Convolutional Neural Network code

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

So I am quite new to tensorflow and python, and I am doing a research project this year where I am developing a simple convolutional neural network that can detect handwriting images and guess which handwriting belongs to who based off of training samples. The images used for this dataset are my own. The problem I am having is that I am running into this error when I compile my code:

```
Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 2 for 'ReadFile' (op: 'ReadFile') with input shapes: [5,4].
```

I looked at a similar post to this and I saw the answer, but the problem is that my code is quite different, and being relatively new to tensorflow, I don't have a deep understanding of some of the code.

Below is my code for my CNN. I used a few online resources and tutorials to construct it:

```
# Import statements
import os, sys
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import *
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.advanced_activations import *
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import *
from tensorflow.python.keras.losses import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from math import floor, ceil
from pylab import rcParams

# Disables the warning
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

# Filename vectors
imageFile = tf.constant([['bob1.jpg', 'bob2.jpg', 'bob3.jpg', 'bob4.jpg'],
                        ['peter1.jpg', 'peter2.jpg', 'peter3.jpg', 'peter4.jpg'],
                        ['steve1.jpg', 'steve2.jpg', 'steve3.jpg', 'steve4.jpg'],
                        ['josh1.jpg', 'josh2.jpg', 'josh3.jpg', 'josh4.jpg'],
                        ['chris1.jpg', 'chris2.jpg', 'chris3.jpg', 'chris4.jpg']])
testFile = tf.constant(['bob5.jpg', 'peter5.jpg', 'steve5.jpg', 'josh5.jpg', 'chris5.jpg'])

# Label vectors
imageLabels = tf.read_file([['bob','bob','bob','bob'],
                        ['peter','peter','peter','peter'],
                        ['steve','steve','steve','steve'],
                        ['josh','josh','josh','josh'],
                        ['chris','chris','chris','chris']])
testLabels = tf.read_file(['bob', 'peter', 'steve', 'josh', 'chris'])

# Resizing function that enables all images to be sized the same
def _resize_function(filename, label):
  image_name = tf.read_file(filename)
  image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_name, channels = 2)
  image = tf.cast(image_decoded, tf.float32)
  image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image, [1290, 560])
  return image_resized, label

# Datasets
trainSet = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((imageFile, imageLabels))
trainSet = trainSet.map(_resize_function)
testSet = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((testFile, testLabels))
testSet = testSet.map(_resize_function)

# Iterators
train_iterator = trainSet.make_one_shot_iterator()
images, labels = trainSet.get_next()
test_iterator = testSet.make_one_shot_iterator()
testImg, testLb = testSet.get_next()

# Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (5, 4, 1, 1), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, input_shape = (5, 4, 1, 1), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, 3, input_shape = (5, 4, 1, 1), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding = 'same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
# FInal layer - flattening
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

# Compilation
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Run. Epochs should be varied as well.
fit = model.fit(images, labels, steps_per_epoch = 4, batch_size = 5, epochs = 2, verbose = 1, validation_data = (testImg, testLb))
score = model.evaluate(testImg, testLb, verbose = 0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Is the error coming from the `_resize_function`, or is it from the labels? If anyone could help me out with this error, that would be great.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the full error message?

Comment: I think the error is coming from `input_shape = (5, 4, 1, 1)` try `input_shape = (5, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

following the track of your post i assume the error you have is coming from here:

```
imageLabels = tf.read_file([['bob','bob','bob','bob'],
                    ['peter','peter','peter','peter'],
                    ['steve','steve','steve','steve'],
                    ['josh','josh','josh','josh'],
                    ['chris','chris','chris','chris']])
```

You are passing a matrix of shape `[5,4]` and from what i understand it is not what is expected by the function.

I think it is a typo and you meant `tf.constant` for the labels, not `tf.read_file` just replace and you should be fine (at least for that part)